# products of values in each set of powerset

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array, lets say array = [ 1,2,3]

I want to find out all the products values in each set of its powerset.

For example,

The power set is

```
{null}
{1} - 1
{2} - 2
{3} - 3
{1,2}- 2
{2,3}- 6
{1,3}- 3
{1,2,3}- 6
```

Notation: set followed by product of values in the set

How can I achieve this using dynamic programming.

Note:

I tried this way, found the powerset by

```
void printPowerSet(int *set, int set_size)
{
    /*set_size of power set of a set with set_size
      n is (2**n -1)*/
    unsigned int pow_set_size = pow(2, set_size);
    int counter, j;

    /*Run from counter 000..0 to 111..1*/
    for(counter = 0; counter < pow_set_size; counter++)
    {

     int product=1;
      for(j = 0; j < set_size; j++)
       {
          /* Check if jth bit in the counter is set
             If set then pront jth element from set */
          if(counter & (1<<j))
           product *= counter;
       }
      printf("%d", product);
    }
}
```

This technique works absolutely fine, but for small arrays, (array size < 32)

Comment: I doubt DP (buttom-up) will improve the answer, the idea of DP is usually building all possibilities from lower to higher, and marking which are valid. However, in here, the range of possibilities is `[1,x1*x2*...*xn]` - which is much worse then `2^n`, assuming all (except maybe one value) `x_i >= 2`.

Comment: @amit: Well, he need not do that; you're not going to use everything in that range. There's a way to do it that uses at worst the number of distinct products (well, `O(number of distinct products)`).

Comment: @DennisMeng how can we achieve this in O(number of distinct products)

Comment: I'll post an answer with pseudocode; it's too messy if I try to make it a comment.

Comment: `pow(2, set_size);` - ***awwwwww....!*** `1 << set_size` FTW!

Comment: @Dukeling But it's wrong.

Comment: @Dukeling I'm saying that it's not the same. Floating-point arithmetic is inexact, you can easily get 7.9999364 from `pow(2, 3)` and then that's suddenly truncated to 7 instead of rounded to 8... Not good, man.

Comment: @H2CO3 Oh right, I tend to forget that there isn't a function for integers.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your input set is `S` and has `size` elements. Something like this would work:

```
make an empty set A
for every element s in S {
    make an empty set B
    for every t in A {
        add s*t to B
    }
    A = union of A and B
}
```

The total memory used at once is then at worst the sum of the sizes of both sets, so `O(number of distinct products))`. Your "subproblem" would be "What are the products that I can get using the first `x` elements of the set?